# Rolling Sum of Sales

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a rolling sum of sales looking into a 5 day lead time in microsoft sql server. So if its the 10th I would like to like at the 5 days leading up to the 10th counting the number of sales made up to that point. I would like this to happen every day, looking 5 days prior to that day. For example says like this:
[image]

I tried the code the image below but I was not getting the correct values.
For example on the 15/06 id expect the code to return a value of 10 sales (1+1+1+3+4) summing all the sales from the 10/06 to 14/06

```
SELECT TOP 100
    DATEFROMPARTS(Year, Month, Day) as Date,
    L.ItemCode,
    L.MinLeadTime,
    DD.Quantity,
    CAST(Sum(DD.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY L.itemcode ORDER BY DATEFROMPARTS(Year, Month, Day) 
          ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS decimal (18,2)) AS [Rolling Sum Sales],
    L.ImpressLevel
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share your simple data, the expected output  and what you have tried as text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20cannot%20be%20interpreted%20by,can't%20be%20zoomed%20in.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Creating some dummy data to use (based on your screenshot, but without the weird incrementing year every 4 days:

```
create table #sales
(
    [date] date,
    sales int
)

insert into #sales values
('2023-06-01',0),
('2023-06-02',2),
('2023-06-03',0),
('2023-06-04',0),
('2023-06-05',0),
('2023-06-06',2),
('2023-06-07',2),
('2023-06-08',0),
('2023-06-09',2),
('2023-06-10',4),
('2023-06-11',3),
('2023-06-12',1),
('2023-06-13',1),
('2023-06-14',1),
('2023-06-15',0),
('2023-06-16',0),
('2023-06-17',2),
('2023-06-18',1),
('2023-06-19',0),
('2023-06-20',9),
('2023-06-21',0),
('2023-06-22',0),
('2023-06-23',0),
('2023-06-24',0),
('2023-06-25',0),
('2023-06-26',0),
('2023-06-27',0),
('2023-06-28',0)
```

You can use [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to achieve this:

```
select
    [date],
    sales,
    sum(s.sales) over ( order by s.[date]
                        rows between 5 preceding
                        and current row) as FiveDaySales
from #sales s
```

giving this output:

```
/-----------------------------------\
|    date    | sales | FiveDaySales |
|------------|-------|--------------| 
| 2023-06-01 |   0   |       0      |
| 2023-06-02 |   2   |       2      |
| 2023-06-03 |   0   |       2      |
| 2023-06-04 |   0   |       2      |
| 2023-06-05 |   0   |       2      |
| 2023-06-06 |   2   |       4      |
| 2023-06-07 |   2   |       6      |
| 2023-06-08 |   0   |       4      |
| 2023-06-09 |   2   |       6      |
| 2023-06-10 |   4   |      10      |
| 2023-06-11 |   3   |      13      |
| 2023-06-12 |   1   |      12      |
| 2023-06-13 |   1   |      11      |
| 2023-06-14 |   1   |      12      |
| 2023-06-15 |   0   |      10      |
| 2023-06-16 |   0   |       6      |
| 2023-06-17 |   2   |       5      |
| 2023-06-18 |   1   |       5      |
| 2023-06-19 |   0   |       4      |
| 2023-06-20 |   9   |      12      |
| 2023-06-21 |   0   |      12      |
| 2023-06-22 |   0   |      12      |
| 2023-06-23 |   0   |      10      |
| 2023-06-24 |   0   |       9      |
| 2023-06-25 |   0   |       9      |
| 2023-06-26 |   0   |       0      |
| 2023-06-27 |   0   |       0      |
| 2023-06-28 |   0   |       0      |
\-----------------------------------/
```

This assumes on each row, you want the sum of the previous 5 days, plus the current day. If this is not the case, just adjust the `rows between` part accordingly.

Comment: This code works but I still have an issue. The code is adding everything correctly but the problem I am having that the tables I am using only collect data on the days there were sales. (no sale no data entry for the date, instead of a 0 value). However I would still like the 0s included in the summation.  How would I add the dates that no sales occurred?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I guess create a date table with every relevant date in it and join to that to get zero values for all the "missing" dates with no sales. For future reference, making this clear in your question (by not including days with "0" sales) would have been helpful.